# how to plot several boxplot with disjoint x buckets

Tags: matplotlib, boxplot

I would like to to plot several boxplots in one plot. There are three groups in my toy example. Group 1 has values of a different magnitude, but should be on the very left side on the plot. Then Group 2-3 should be appended on the x-axis and have a y-axis on the right hand side. I tried via `ax.twinx()`. However, this is not fully correct, as they don't share the complete x-axis. But the order on the `x-axis` is important, i.e. Group 1 needs to appear before Group 2 followed by Group 3. Unfortunately, now my Group 2 gets plotted on the same x position as Group 1. Group 3 is plotted on the x-position of Group 2 instead further right

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df_plot  = pd.DataFrame([[0, 10],[0, 10.1],[0, 9.8],[1, 0.4],[1, 0.2], [1, 0.9], [2, 1.2], [2, 0.2], [2, 1]], columns=["x","y"])
x_ticklable = ["Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3"]
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(2560/120, 1335/120))
sns.boxplot(data=df_plot[df_plot["x"] <= 0],
            x="x", y="y",
            ax=ax1)
plt.yticks(fontsize=16)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
sns.boxplot(data=df_plot[df_plot["x"] > 0],
            x="x", y="y",
            ax=ax2)
ax2.set_ylabel("")
ax1.set_ylabel("Y level",
               fontsize="22")
ax1.set_xlabel("Buckets", fontsize="22")
ax1.xaxis.set_ticks(list(range(len(x_ticklable))), fontsize=16)
ax1.set_xticklabels(x_ticklable, fontsize=16)
plt.xticks(fontsize=16)
plt.yticks(fontsize=16)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `order` parameter of `seaborn.boxplot` function for the second boxplot should fix your overlap issue.

Here is working example that should create the figure you want

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df_plot  = pd.DataFrame([[0, 10],[0, 10.1],[0, 9.8],[1, 0.4],[1, 0.2], [1, 0.9], [2, 1.2], [2, 0.2], [2, 1]], columns=["x","y"])
x_ticklabels = ["Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3"]

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(2560/120, 1335/120))

ax1.set_xlim(0, 2)
# By default, will create a boxplot at position x=0 
sns.boxplot(data=df_plot[df_plot["x"] <= 0], x="x", y="y", ax=ax1) 
plt.yticks(fontsize=16)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()

# Explicitly set the order of the boxplot. 
# Will create a boxplot at position x=1 and x=2 (based on "x" value)
sns.boxplot(data=df_plot[df_plot["x"] > 0], x="x", y="y", ax=ax2, order=[0, 1, 2])

ax1.set_ylabel("Y level", fontsize="22")
ax1.set_xlabel("Buckets", fontsize="22")
ax1.set_xticklabels(x_ticklabels, fontsize=16)

ax1.grid()
ax1.set_axisbelow(True)

plt.xticks(fontsize=16)
plt.yticks(fontsize=16)
```

[image]